# Dynamic Registration/Un-Registration of topics - leading to offset issues

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

We are trying to leverage Dynamic Kafka Topic Listening (based on approach https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-boot-start-stop-a-kafka-listener-dynamically/) to handle disaster recovery of the Kafka consumers.

We are witnessing issues wrt this implementation using spring kafka, where in after disaster recovery we are not able to sync offsets at Target site. (using MM2).

Below is the problem detail:

Kafka Clusters: A, B
Cluster A Topic : t2
Cluster B Topic (Mirrored) : A.t2
Consumer Group : G1

1. Under the normal circumstance data is processed from Cluster A.
2. If there is disaster we are trying to process data from Cluster B (Topic : A.t2, as it has data and offset synced) and commit offsets.
3. The offset sync from Cluster B to A happens once Cluster A is back. (MM2 bidirectional does it or we can move offset manually).
4. Once A is back we are deregistering the Cluster B - Topic A.t2, as it can be processed from Main cluster.
5. Messages produced and consumed from Cluster A(Topic T2) from here on.
6. Offset sync to cluster B??? (A.T2)

This concept is working alright for console produce/consumer or kafka-java consumer.

We are seeing issues with spring kafka - At Step#6, where in after dynamic registration/deregistration of the topic its not able to get offset sync from Cluster A. (May be some sort of leakage, although we deregistered topic at Cluster B)

Kafka version: kafka_2.13-3.1.0
Spring Kafka version : 2.9.6

**MM2 Config:**

```
clusters=A, B  

# connection information for each cluster
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs for each cluster
# for e.g. "A_host1:9092, A_host2:9092, A_host3:9092"
A.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093,localhost:9094  
B.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9095,localhost:9096  

A->B.enabled=true  
A->B.topics=t2,B.t2  
A->B.groups=10  
B->A.enabled=true  
B->A.topics=t2,A.t2  
B->A.groups=10  
A->B.sync.group.offsets=true   
B->A.sync.group.offsets=true  
A->B.sync.group.offsets.enabled=true  
B->A.sync.group.offsets.enabled=true  
A->B.emit.checkpoints.enabled=true  
B->A.emit.checkpoints.enabled=true  

refresh.groups.enabled=true  
groups.blacklist=console-consumer-.*, connect-.*,__.*
config.properties.blacklist=follower\\.replication\\.throttled\\.replicas,leader\\.replication\\.throttled\\.replicas,message\\.timestamp\\.difference\\.max\\.ms,message\\.timestamp\\.type,unclean\\.leader\\.election\\.enable,min\\.insync\\.replicas  
topics.blacklist=connect-.*, .*[\\-\\.]internal, __.*, .*\\.replica  
sync.topic.acls.enabled=true  
emit.heartbeats.enabled=true  
emit.checkpoints.enabled=true  
refresh.topics.enabled=true  
sync.topic.configs.enabled=true  

offset.storage.replication.factor=1  
status.storage.replication.factor=1  
config.storage.replication.factor=1  

checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=1  
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=1  
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=1
```

**Spring config:**

```
@Bean(name = "consumerFactory1")
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory1() {

    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory1")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory1() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory1());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Also, if the problem only happens in Spring-Kafka, and not any other JVM consumer, then show your code + those configs as a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.. It did not work for spring kafka as mentioned in problem. Edited question with updated config.

Comment: You're still missing your Spring configs and code so that anyone can try to reproduce your problem... If it works without spring, then MM2 config isn't the problem

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Will add the code and update you further.

Comment: With spring kafka we are observing the error like in the mm2 logs.  ERROR [MirrorCheckpointConnector|task-0] [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-32] OffsetCommit request for group id 10 and partition A.t2-0 failed due to unexpected error UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AlterConsumerGroupOffsetsHandler:198)

Comment: Those are internal logs to the Connector tasks, and have nothing to do with usage of a specific client, though. The AdminClient communicates with the brokers, not your Spring code... Unless - are you trying to run MirrorMaker2 from _within_ a Spring application?

Comment: mm2 is run with simple sh command.. (Not from spring). But observing the above failure in logs everytime when the offset is not getting synced to the target cluster. (When topic is registered, deregistered as mentioned above) .

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed. The problem was using the same group name we were consuming another topic in the same consumer. This was causing offset sync issue from mm2.
From one of the forum. Few hints from below.

https://dattell.com/data-architecture-blog/how-to-fix-the-member_id-error-in-kafka/

"Always use a unique consumer group id per topic/group.  Using the same consumer group id across multiple topics can cause issues during consumer rebalancing events."